# OSX Yosemite USB Flash Drive Missing Space Issue

Tags: macos, usb, usb-flash-drive, osx-yosemite, macbook-pro-retina

I purchased a 128GB flash drive.
Available space after exFat formatting is 123.6GB
I transfer roughly 25GB (a TON of files beyond the 100,000 range) from another flash drive onto this one.

I now have 69GB left on the 128GB flash drive...after a supposed 25GB transfer.
Can someone please explain to me what is going on here?

OS X Yosemite. Macbook Pro 2014.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the issue. OS X get info wasn't showing the true size. Only 1 program did however, called DiskDaisy. Re-zipped all of my unzipped files/folders on the drive and I was back to the 22GB of used space.